# How to pickle python object which has reference to cytpes library

Tags: python, pickle, ctypes, dill

I am trying to pickle python function which uses ctypes object to call some function.

I have created a '.so' file with my sum function which I am trying to invoke in my python code

c code

```
#include <stdio.h>


int sum(int a, int b) {

    return a + b;

}
```

use in python code

```
from ctypes import cdll
libsum = cdll.LoadLibrary("libsum.so")

def cal_sum(param1, param2):
    return libsum.sum(param1, param2)
```

When I try to pickle the cal_sum function using

```
out = open("/tmp/abc", "wb")
cloudpickle.dump(cal_sum, out)
out.close()
```

I am getting below error

`TypeError: can't pickle getset_descriptor objects`.

Is there any way we can pickle such function